# In android, why am I getting a `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` needed error despite having it defined?

Tags: android, gps

Im getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
```

In my android code despite having:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in my manifest.xml

Here is my code causing the error. It is wrapped to check for permissions but the first line in the if still causes that error.

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
}
```

I also have the `LocationListener` `onLocationChanged` event defined before that.

Do I need to add anything else to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
}
```

if the permission is not granted, you need to `requestPermission`

Comment: how do I request permission?

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

Answer (score 0):

You should request permission at run-time for devices running Android 6.0 and above. Below is a sample

```
private String locationPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, locationPermission)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
} else {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
      new String[] { locationPermission }, PR_LOCATION_REQUEST);
}
```

And handle the permission grant result as

```
@Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
  @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
if (requestCode != PR_LOCATION_REQUEST) {
  super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  return;
}
if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 1, mLocationListener);
  return;
}
}
```

Refer this for more details https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html